# Use self-signed certificate as digital ID in Outlook

Tags: outlook, ssl-certificate, digital-signature

I need to test some encrypting feature inside outlook in an internal network. I'm trying to setup S/MIME encryption for 2 users and exchange some encrypted mails between them.

I generated 2 self-signed certificates (public and private) using makecert.exe

I imported them on both user (different machine, same exchange) respectivly
by entering the certificate file path, password and name in the outlook trust center. Outlook process and close the window. I go under security settings and select the certificate.

I also added the certificate under Trust Root/Personal/Trusted Person in windows certificate store.

Now, I'm trying to test this by making a message from user1 to user2 , the window prompt to select a certificate to "sign" the message and it says that there are none available.

Update: I also imported the public certificate of both users in contacts to make encrypting available. Still the same message when I try to send the mail, it says that no certificates can be use to send this message.

UPDATE: The same procedure looks functional in outlook 2007 but does not work in 2010.

What the ***!! How come is it so complicated and what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by installing a CA server in my network and issued both certificates from there. I couldn't make the self-sign work in 2010.